# More information in signal/slot with QPushButton

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, signals

When I implements the function that is executed when a button is clicked, the code is like this:

```
self.connect(btnBrowse, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.browseFile)
```

and I implement the function `browseFile`

```
def browseFile(self):
```

But when i am inside the method browseFile, I don't have information about the button being clicked, because I want to implement just one function `browseFile` for many buttons. how can I do to have more information the slot, for example to have my function looks like this:

```
def browseFile(self, option):
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to a lambda (or use [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.partial)).
Also note the use of new style syntax, which is much more readable and pythonic.

```
self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(lambda: self.browseFile(option))
```

Comment: This is the best answer for my question!

Comment: Didn't know you could do that !

Answer (score 1):

[Sender()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#sender) provides a pointer to the button that sent the event, you can then read the button text (or other associated data) to determine which button was pressed